# How to escape forward slash '/' within a regex condition in flux query

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2

I have to query an InFlux database and match a particular string within one of columns.

something like:   `WHERE (\"namecache\" =~ /<match_string>/)`

however, the **<match_string>** could itself contain '/' characters. I am unable to escape the forward slashes within the match string because of which the query fails.

Is there a way to escape the '/' slashes? or is there an alternate way to match partial strings?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that escaping the '/' will fix this. use '\' as the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

For escaping any string
`/api/v2/kyc/verify` we need to use `\` as an escape character to frame
`\/api\/v2\/kyc\/verify` way to put into regex